# How to use dplyr to filter rows where value in a specific column is 1 and all the rest are 0?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

Using `dplyr` functions, I want to remove rows in which only column `b` equals `1` and the *rest* of columns are all `0`.

Although I can do this:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

trb <-
  tribble(~a, ~b, ~c,
          1, 1, 1,
          1, 1, 0,
          1, 0, 1,
          0, 1, 0, # <~~~ remove this
          0, 0, 0,
          0, 1, 0  # <~~~ remove this
          )

trb %>%
  filter(!(b == 1 & a == 0 & c == 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     1     0
#> 3     1     0     1
#> 4     0     0     0
```

I'm looking for a more scalable solution to account for data such as:

```r
trb_2 <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~a, ~b, ~c, ~d, ~e, ~f, ~g, ~h, ~i, ~j, ~k, ~l, ~m, ~n, ~o, ~p, ~q, ~r, ~s, ~t, ~u, ~v, ~w, ~x, ~y, ~z,
    0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,
    0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,
    0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,
    1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1
  )
```

In `trb_2` I still want to remove the rows in which `b` equals `1` ***and*** all the rest are `0`.

---

Is there a scalable way to achieve this using `dplyr::filter()`?

Comment: From your last edit it looks like you want to **keep only** rows where b is 1 and others are 0. I thought you asked to **remove** only these rows? Which is correct?

Comment: Sorry you're right. My bad. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the new helper function `dplyr::if_all()` you can do this for no matter how many columns you have:

```r
trb %>% 
  filter(!(b == 1 & if_all(-b, ~ .x == 0)))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     1     1     0
3     1     0     1
4     0     0     0
```

Breakdown of `!(b == 1 & if_all(-b, ~ .x == 0))`:

- `b == 1` will match rows where b is 1
- `if_all(-b, ~ .x == 0)` will match rows where all columns except b are exactly 0
- `!(b == 1 & if_all(-b, ~ .x == 0))` combines these two expressions and removes the rows where both are true

Answer (score 2):

```r
trb %>%
  filter(b != 1 | rowSums(. == 1) != 1)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#       a     b     c
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     1     1     0
# 3     1     0     1
# 4     0     0     0
```